# Datatype is money, how to replace 0 with empty in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Datatype of column1 is `money`, I would like to replace 0 with empty.

I have tried the following, but it still shows 0

```
CASE 
   WHEN column1 = 0 
      THEN '' 
      ELSE column1 
END
```

This is in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: `''` is a string not a number, perhaps you are looking for `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Use NULL instead

```
CASE WHEN column1 = 0 THEN NULL ELSE column1 END
```

Answer (score 0):

The column needs to be *nullable*, and then you can simply use `NULL`

```
CASE WHEN column1 = 0 THEN NULL ELSE column1 END
```